# How can I stop input repeating for each char inputted?

Tags: c++, recursion, user-input, cin

I'm trying to write a prompt where it asks the user to confirm an operation, with Y/N as the only two options.

If the user inputs Y, it does something, if the user inputs N it does something else. However if the user inputs anything other than Y or N, it simply repeats the question until either Y or N is pressed.

This is what i've got so far:

```
char result = '\0';

while (result != 'y' || result != 'n')
{
  char key = '\0';
  cout << "Do you wish to continue & overwrite the file? Y/N: ";
  cin >> key;
  result = tolower(key);
}

if (result == 'y')
{
  cout << "YES!" << endl;
}
else if (result == 'n')
{
  cout << "NO!" << endl;
}
```

And my problem is that if I enter multiple invalid characters, it displays the prompt again for each invalid character, like so:

```
Do you wish to continue & overwrite the file? Y/N: abc
a
Do you wish to continue & overwrite the file? Y/N: b
Do you wish to continue & overwrite the file? Y/N: c
Do you wish to continue & overwrite the file? Y/N:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but, in what case, do you expect `while (result != 'y' || result != 'n')` to terminate? The only possible combination of values, in the expression, where it results in a `false` (i.e. breaking out of the loop) would be for `result` to be equal to `'y'`, and `'n'` **at the same time**. Which is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I've realised my II condition was wrong too, it should have been &&. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So if my input was stored as a string (rather than a char), I wouldn't get the repetition for each char inputted. Also, my while loop condition should have been AND instead of OR:

```
string result = "";

while (result != "y" && result != "n")
{
  cout << "Do you wish to continue & overwrite the file? Y/N: ";
  cin >> result;
  transform(result.begin(), result.end(), result.begin(), ::tolower);
}

if (result == "y")
{
  cout << "YES!" << endl;
}
else if (result == "n")
{
  cout << "NO!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Typical default initialization of string would be an empty string, `string result = "";`. Make sure not to treat strings like chars. Your code still works fine, though.